# display data from web service

Tags: jquery, ajax, cordova

```
$.ajax(
        {
            url:"http://date.jsontest.com",
            type:"GET",             
            accepts:"utf-8",
            success: function(data){

                    navigator.notification.alert("successful"+data.toString());

            },
            error: function(){
                    navigator.notification.alert("Unsuccessful");
            }
        });
```

The above code does not display data coming from web service. It only shows an alert box with the "successful" string.

How would I solve this issue?

Comment: Did you tried `JSON.parse(data)` and you get a vale from the Javascript object result? You can also try showing only the `data` like `"succesful" + data`. Your server should return it as string, so `.toStrting()` method is not needed. Check that your server is returning some data.

Comment: Have you tried to console.log data to make sure it has a value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add the **dataType** to your ajax call, like:

```
dataType: "json",
```

and you should be able to get data in success method like :

```
console.log("successful: " + data.time);
alert("successful: " + data.time);
```

Actually, your ajax call gives the following results:

```
{
   "time": "10:21:31 AM",
   "milliseconds_since_epoch": 1368440491978,
   "date": "05-13-2013"
}
```

I have just got the **time** in the alert, you can get the other values also in similar way.

Comment: now going forward each json string can be access by using its key value?

Comment: You have three keys here: `time, milliseconds_since_epoch & date`. In order access each of the strings, you have to use the respective keys. For ex, `time` for string `"10:21:31 AM"`, `date` for the string `"05-13-2013"`, etc. That's it. Hope you got it!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use like this

```
$.ajax({
            cache : false,
            type : 'GET',
            async : false,
            url : "URL",
            data : "<hello></hello>",
            dataType : "xml",
            success : function(xml) {
                var endUser = $(xml).find('Username').eq(0).text();
                var admin = $(xml).find('Username').eq(1).text();
                var endUserPassword = $(xml).find('Password').eq(0).text();
                var adminPassword = $(xml).find('Password').eq(1).text();
                checkLogin(endUser, endUserPassword);
            },

            error : function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                alert("Error while loading the Service !!!");
                $.mobile.loading('hide');
            }
        });
```

Comment: Why `async: false`? It's highly **NOT** recommended to set async property to false, only if it is absolutly needed. If you use ajax, by default it's async and you want to use it for some reason.

Comment: The question is not Coming under WEbApp is PhoneGAp, So there is no PostBack kind of thing in PhoneGap - Android. Code I Implemented in my Application

Answer (score 0):

Try to use json dataType. if you are getting array in reponse. just encode that array with json_encode function like echo json_encode(array); and in success msg try to fetch reponce with . so data.index1, data.index2

```
$.ajax({
            cache : false,
            type : 'GET',
            url : "URL",
            dataType : "json",
            success : function(data) {
                             alert(data.index);
            },

            error : function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me...

```
function getTest() {
       $.ajax({
           type: 'GET',
           contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
           dataType: 'jsonp',
           url: 'http://date.jsontest.com?callback=?',
           data: '{}',
           success: function (data) {

              alert(data.date);

           },
           error: function (a) {
               alert(a.responseText);
           }
       });
   }
```

Answer (score -1):

In your success function, use:

`$('.ajax_content').html(data);`

That will display the content in a div with an ID of ajax_content so obviously change the ID or create the ajax_content div.

Comment: that's not what he's asking to do